# windows service email with timer

Tags: c#, email, windows-services, timer

I am creating a windows service project which sends bulk email in  particular time interval(Just say in every 30 Mins). I am having the email data stored in the data base. I am having a function to send the email. Can any one suggest me that how can i send the emails asynchronously.

Can i use threading.tasks?

Please share the sample code

Thanks
San

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which language is being used by you for development but the following link describes sending mails asynchronously using SMTPClient.

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SendSmtpAsync.aspx

Hope this would help.